# Write to current cursor cursor position using a neovim Python plugin

Tags: neovim, neovim-python-client

I'd like to insert uuids into my tests when I need them without having to leave vim. I've tried to create a python3 plugin to do this:

```
import neovim 
import uuid

@neovim.plugin
class GenerateUuid(object):
    def __init__(self, vim):
        self.vim = vim
        self.current_line = vim.current.line
    

    @neovim.function('GetUuid')
    def getUuid(self, args):
        id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        # copy to clipboard
        self.vim.current.line = self.current_line + id
```

When I edit a new line in my file to look like:

```
// start of file
import fs from 'fs';

let id =
```

and run `:exec GetUuid()` I see that it inserts the uuid into the first line instead to look like this:

```
import fs from 'fs'; 10436f81-fe16-43a4-abe4-9e4b2599854f
```

I'd like to append it at the current cursor position and copy it to the clipboard. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly an answer to your question because I don't feel like digging in some python plugin code. This is just an alternative way covering only the need you presented.

---

What about something much simpler than your whole plugin? For example you could add these lines to your vimrc:

```
command! GetUuid let @a=systemlist("python -c 'import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())'")[0]|norm! "ap
inoremap <uniq_mapping> <C-o>:GetUuid<CR>
```

The first line creates a new command `:GetUuid`. This command uses [`:h systemlist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#systemlist%28%29) to get the output of the shell command `python -c 'import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())'` (which prints a uuid). It puts the output of the command in the register `a` and then paste the register after the cursor position.

I'm using `systemlist()` instead of [`:h system()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) to avoid getting the newline in the result. There is a drawback of poluting your register `a` but you could choose any other one. To avoid that, one could use [`:h :put`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aput) with the following command but it has the issue of putting the inserted text on a different line:

```
command! GetUuid put =systemlist('python3 -c \"import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())\"')[0]
```

And the second line is an example of how to create an insert mode mapping to add the uuid without leaving the insert mode.

Comment: possibly `:command GetUUID put =systemlist('python3 -c \"import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())\"')[0] | join`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that didn't work for me, I had to use `command! GetUUID put =systemlist('python3 -c \"import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())\"')[0] | norm! kJ` But I suspect there are some edge cases where this would not be perfect neither.

Comment: Oh, maybe `-join` then?

Answer (score 2):

In my question, I asked for a Python3 neovim plugin solution. This answer is just for completion:

```python
def insert_at_cursor(self, value):
       row, col = self.vim.current.window.cursor
       current_line = self.vim.current.buffer[row - 1]
       new_line = current_line[:col] + value + current_line[col:] 
       self.vim.current.buffer[row - 1] = new_line
```